# How to peroperly connect and disconnect redis client from cloud functions/cloud run services

Tags: redis, google-cloud-functions, ioredis

I'm trying Redis for my project backend that rely on cloud functions with HTTP trigger and Express routing and I have connection leak because Redis client is not disconnected when the function finished. I'm going to use cloud run for microservices in the future so I think it might have same problem so I decided to ask first.

I tried process.on("exit", ()=> {}); but it won't work.

Comment: Please add a [mnimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your function. Also, the code to close your Redis connection might be called as a part of your function itself as its env will be teared down when it's done. Also, are you sure that the error is due to that the connection pool is full?

Comment: it not error. I watch metric in Redis cloud and it show that connections number aren't down when functions is complete. I need to wait for 5 minutes for the number to reduce, that is real time value

Comment: On Cloud Run (or Cloud Functions gen2), you can use the sigterm https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#instance-shutdown It's a good practice to keep the connection active while the instance is active to reduce the latency (perform the connection process only once per instance)